# Gstreamer kivy dependencies not installing on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, kivy, gstreamer

Whenever I use the command from the /docs section on the kivy website to install gstreamer, I receive:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy.deps.gstreamer (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for kivy.deps.gstreamer

Kivy itself runs fine, however.

Comment: From Kivy website: `gstreamer is an optional dependency which only needs to be installed if video display or audio is desired.`

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However, I do wish to import video and/or audio. So I would like to know how to install this dependecy